How remove rigify settings from armature
I downloaded one model & instead of usual armature there it's configured via Rigify or something similar. Is there a way to remove all these settings so that only simple armature remains?
I tried to manually clean armature, deleted all constraints & drivers, unlocked all locks that I can found. But armature still doesn't work as it should. Some bones are scaled only along the Y axis, although it seems that they are not locked anywhere. And when I tried to attach clothes, for example, spine, which doesn't scale, that it doesn't react to its bones at all. Therefore, is it possible to somehow completely remove any settings from armature & remove unnecessary bones from all settings & leave only clean armature?
I want to edit model, but all these ready-made settings prevent me from doing it.

Hello could you please share the armature?

Here is that downloaded file with ready armature settings: https://dropmefiles.com/lerT8. Is it possible to somehow remove all these settings & extra bones along with them & leave only standard bones?

I can't download from this site for some reason, could you please use another platform?

Hmm, it's strange that you can't download. The link is working. But OK, here, I uploaded it to another place: https://transfiles.ru/53z7n.

You can see the basic armature (the bones that have the Deform option activated) in the Data panel > Bone Collections > Layer 10:

If you want to remove the custom appearance in Pose mode, go into the Bone panel and click on both Alt and the X on the right of the Custom Object name:

If you want to display the bones as octahedrals, in the Data panel choose Display As > Octahedral:


Yes! It worked! I was just working with the wrong bones. But now after clearing all restrictions & when I connected all bones, everything started working perfectly. I finally got usual armature that I edited without any problems. Thanks a lot for your help!
